# Delphi DataSnap REST server returning JSON array from a TStream not binary

Tags: rest, delphi

I have a REST server that talks to an Android client.  I upgraded it from XE3(ish) to Berlin.  One of the server methods returned a TStream that contained a jpeg it and worked great happily returning the image as a binary image.  After upgrading to Berlin it now returns a JSON array.  Is there anyway I can get the server to return a binary stream rather than a JSON array?

Some example code

```
function TServerMethods1.GetImage: TStream;
begin
  result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  (result as TMemoryStream).LoadFromFile(SomeImage);
end;
```

which returns a rather sizable array

```
{"result":[[255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73.....]]}
```

as opposed to the binary version: `ÿØÿàJFIF.....`

Comment: I can't answer the question but I know I read something about this recently in the Delphi online help about how to modify the REST request from the Android client to request the data as a stream.  It was specifically in relation to the default behaviour changing to yield an array.

Comment: In Portugese, but you could use Google Translate to translate it: http://vivaitaocara.com.br/landersongomes/embarcadero/delphi/transferindo-imagem-via-datasnap-rest-parte-1

Comment: Thanks @DaveNottage, but not quite what I'm after.  The article describes how to return an image base 64 encoded.

Comment: According to the doco, you can add a ?json=true parameter to the request.  Does setting it to false return the raw stream?

Comment: @Jason you are correct.  Now I just need to work out how to somehow make this the default behavior.  Maybe through some sort of URL rewrite or property.