# Content-Type response in the REST DataSnap not working for me

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I build a DataSnap REST server with the wizard in Embarcadero® Delphi 10.4 Architect. I need to create a simple method to get a PDF file from a client, such as Postman.

I wrote the next code after reading [Return an image from a Delphi REST server and show it in a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13879238/):

```pascal
function TServerMethods1.GetPdf: TFileStream;
var
 fStream: TFileStream;
begin
 fStream := TFileStream.Create('images/ticket.pdf', fmOpenread or fmShareDenyNone);
 GetInvocationMetadata.ResponseContentType := 'application/pdf';
 Result := fStream;
end;
```

In the AfterDispatch event:

```pascal
procedure TWebModule1.WebModuleAfterDispatch(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest;
  Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.ContentType := 'application/pdf';
end;
```

But when I call the method from postman, I get an error because the result is a JSON file, not a PDF:

```json
{"result":[[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,55,10,37,226,2...]]}
```

The Content-Type value is OK.

[image: postam header results]

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: As exlained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46536858/delphi-datasnap-rest-server-returning-json-array-from-a-tstream-not-binary), you can disable the JSON output by appending `?json=false` to the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Oliver said in the comments, just add the parameter `?json=false` to the URL

[image: Postman]

It work!!!